# Uninitialized arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

Say that I have an array of some composite type in Julia. I understand that I can't simply assign values into the array since its elements are undefined. For example the code

```
type struct
  u::Int64
  v::Int64
end

X = Array(struct, 100)
X[10].u = 3
```

will generate this error:

```
ERROR: access to undefined reference
 in getindex at array.jl:277
 in include at boot.jl:238
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114
```

What is the standard way to deal with this? For now I am just doing something like:

```
samples = Array(Sample1d, num_samples)
fill!(samples, Sample1d(0, 0, 0))
samples[i] = ...
```

Is there a more concise or Julian way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `fill` to create and fill an array at the same time:

```
type struct
  u::Int
  v::Int
end

struct() = struct(0, 0)
X = fill(struct(), 100)
X[10].u = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign values to uninitialized locations in arrays. You just can't extract values from uninitialized locations.